How to await on something inside async_scoped::TokioScope::scope_and_block?
I need to use async_scoped to run some threads that access non 'static. But I also need to immediately run some async methods and work with their responses in that same scope. How can I do that?
The scope created by scope_and_block is not async so .await cannot be used.
I tried scope.spawn_blocking, but it won't accept the async function directly, complaining that it wants a closure. Also, scope.spawn_blocking returns nothing. I suppose one might be able to box something that the closure would then update, but it seems to be getting rather messy and I'm not sure exactly how/if that would work. Is there a straightforward solution?
So, using the example from the async_scoped docs, how can I make a call to need_async_value(), wait for it to complete and get it's return value so I can use it in that block?
async fn need_async_value() -> i64 {
    5
}

async fn scoped_futures() {
    let not_copy = String::from("hello world!");
    let not_copy_ref = &not_copy;
    let (foo, outputs) = async_scoped::TokioScope::scope_and_block(|s| {
        for _ in 0..10 {
            let x = need_async_value().await; // <- compile error: not in async block
            let proc = || async {
                assert_eq!(not_copy_ref, "hello world!");
                eprintln!("Hello world!")
            };
            s.spawn(proc());
        }
        42
    });
    assert_eq!(foo, 42);
    assert_eq!(outputs.len(), 10);
}

Update:
A comment suggested to use block_on. I tried that:
Handle::current().block_on(need_async_value());

but received the following error:
Cannot start a runtime from within a runtime. This happens because a function (like `block_on`) attempted to block the current thread while the thread is being used to drive asynchronous tasks.

You can use block_on for that.

That method is on the runtime. What would be the correct way to get the runtime? I tried it using Handle.current().block_on and it gave error.

It is block_on as the comment mentioned, but not tokio's block_on, rather futures block_on.
This seems to be working:
let x = futures::executor::block_on(need_async_value());

I also found that another (nested) scope_and_block will work, but that's overkill.
